# Mocha route testing not executing asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, supertest

I have started working with mocha and I have a problem with one particular test case. Here is the code:

```
var assert = require("chai").assert;
var request = require('supertest');
var http = require("http");
var conf = require("../config/config");
var app = require("../app");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

describe('User controller', function(){
  describe('POST /register', function(){
     it('should return false when the parameters are not unique', function (done) {
        request(app)
           .post('/user/register')
           .send({username:"janette_doe", email:"janette_doe@gmail.com", password:"test123"})
           .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
           .expect({success:true, redirect:'/user/registerConfirmation'})
           .end(function(err, res) {
              if (err) {
                 return done(err);
              }

              request(app)
                 .post('/user/register')
                 .send({username:"janette_doe", email:"janette_doe@gmail.com", password:"test123"})
                 .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
                 .expect({success:false}, done);
     });
  });
});
```

I am expecting the result to be false because after the insertion of a user inside the database, the unique index rule should raise an error. When I run this test, I get this: `{success: true, redirect: '/user/registerConfirmation'}` , I should be getting this: `{success: false}`. I noticed that when I don't clear the database before each tests (in utils.js) I am getting the expected value. Do I get this error because of an asynchronous error? How can I rewrite this test to make sure that it works?

Thanks

### Files

**util.js** contains the configurations for the test sequence:

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var config = require('../config/config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

beforeEach(function (done) {

    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();

    return done();
});

afterEach(function (done) {
    return done();
});
```

**user.js** the user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type: Number, default:0}
});

UserSchema.virtual('date')
    .get(function(){
        return this._id.getTimestamp();
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    //Password encryption ...
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**user.js (controller)** is the controller for all the user routes.

```
...

router.post('/register', function (req,res,next){
    var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username
        , email: req.body.email
        , password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send({success: false});
        }else{
            var newToken = new UserToken({
                userId: newUser._id
                , email: newUser.email
            });

            newToken.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.send({success: false});
                }else{
                    res.send({success: true, redirect: '/user/registerConfirmation'});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

...
```

---

### Edit

I have tried the end() function and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in how you chain supertest requests in your test test suite - the second request is not invoked properly. When you were not clearing the database the test was failing on the first `.expect({success: true, ...})` and you were getting the expected value.

The correct way is to perform the first request with `.end` method, check for potential errors, and then perform the second request to see if it has failed:

```
describe('User controller', function(){
   describe('POST /register', function(){
      it('should return false when the parameters are not unique', function (done) {
        request(app)
        .post('/user/register')
        .send({username:"janette_doe", email:"janette_doe@gmail.com", password:"test123"})
        .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
        .expect({success:true, redirect:'/user/registerConfirmation'})
        .end(function(err, res) {

            // Check if first request has failed (it should not!)
            if (err) {
               return done(err);
            }

            // Testing the second, not unique request. that should fail
            request(app)
            .post('/user/register')
            .send({username:"janette_doe", email:"janette_doe@gmail.com", password:"test123"})
            .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
            .expect({success:false}, done);

        });
   });
});
```

Comment: I still get the error. It makes sens for the end function! I will integrate it in the final solution...

Answer (score 1):

In mocha, the done() function should be called when your async call is done - regardless of whether an error is hit. Also, use the .done() function - which is part of the promise API - to end the promise chain and ensure any exceptions are caught. Without the done function, you can miss runtime errors completely, as they are suppressed by the promise library.